# Are ffmpeg prores files reliable enough to be used in production/broadcast environment?

Tags: ffmpeg, prores, libav, apple

Recently I'm transcoding a lot of material that I wish to use in broadcast and production environment where they use all sort of macs and apple software.

I'm not very fan of apple computers and I already own various pc to carry out normal jobs.

What I wonder about is.. is ffmpeg or ffmbc or libav good in producing prores? I mean good enough (producing high compatible files) to make me not in the need of use an apple only for produce pro res files for my customers ?

What documented glitch, issues or problems people who use my ffmpeg prores on final cut or other apple softwares can experience ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've had no problems producing prores 422 HQ .mov files with ffmpeg on my Windows machine for Mac-encumbered clients, including delivery to TV Networks for broadcast. I have had some problems with prores 4444 but only when the files have alpha channels, however that bug seems to have been [fixed recently](https://video.stackexchange.com/questions/20024/bad-quality-encodes-to-prores4444-with-alpha-from-ffmpeg/20037?noredirect=1#comment31737_20037).

I don't know if anyone has done any head to head tests with the results you get out of ffmpeg vs a native apple app or something like adobe media encoder. That would certainly be worth doing.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, I will definitively start using it into my workflow. Just for the info, which software do you use in conjunction of ffmpeg? Premiere, After Effects ?

Comment: Mostly my production chain involves Resolve, then Premiere + AE then ffmpeg for delivery.

Comment: I Agree.Both ProRes and DNxHD are ideal for both post-production and final delivery of TV shows and commercials.

Comment: If you're looking for cross-platforms alternatives to ProRes for intermediate codecs it's also worth considering Cineform. It supports high bit depths and can support alpha channels, is similar in quality, and is gaining increasing adoption in professional workflows.